# Switch from 1 to random real in Jordan Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Context : Let's suppose $L$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R^k}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ , $k$ strictly positive integer. Let's suppose $\epsilon$ is a strictly positive real.

In an exercice , i have to show that there exists a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{C}^k $ such that , $L$ has a upper triangular representation and that in this basis , every coefficient of the matrix representation of L is strictly inferior to $\epsilon$.

I want to say : In $\mathbb{C}^k$ , caracteristic polynomial of L is splitable , a basis in $\mathbb{C}^k$ in which L is upper triangular exists. In particular , there exists a basis $(a_i)_i$ in which L can be written in jordan form. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form  for a definition i guess)

But i can't figure out how to find a particular one respecting "very coefficient of the matrix representation of L is strictly inferior to $\epsilon$.".
I found a clue that says that the basis $b_i=\epsilon^{i-1}a_i$ $i \in [0,k]$) works ,but i don't really figure out why,can someone explain ? or correct,

**edit : thanks Spencer Leslie for the comment , i think i've been neglecting the hypothesis : the correction i make on the coefficient is i want $\vert m_{i,j}\vert <\epsilon  \ \forall i,j,\ 1 \leq i<j\leq k$** (every non diagonal coefficient)

Edit 2 : correcting some terminology mistakes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true without some assumptions on $L$. For example, just take $L=I_k$ to be the identity linear map. The matrix representation will be the same for any choice of basis since $L(v)=v$ for all $v\in \mathbb{R}^k$, and it fails the claim as soon as $0<\epsilon <1$.

Comment: By the way, the ordinary terminology is "upper triangular" representation, not "superior triangular".

Comment: Maybe you mean "every non-diagonal" coefficient? The diagonal coefficients of the upper triangular representation of $L$ will be the eigenvalues and even of all the entries of the matrix representing $L$ with respect to the standard basis are less than $\varepsilon$, it isn't true that all the eigenvalues will be less than $\varepsilon$.